# How to parallelize this C++ code to reduce run-time as much as possible?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

I am trying to reduce the run-time of this code as much as possible. I have never done parallelization in C++. I would appreciate your help in figuring this out. I can run the code on VSCode or CodeLite on a 64-bit Windows machine.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const unsigned long long int MAXVAL = 100000;
    unsigned long long int a;
    for (a = 1; a <= MAXVAL; a++)
    {
        unsigned long long int b;
        for (b = a + 1; b <= MAXVAL; b++)
        {
            unsigned long long int c;
            for (c = b + 1; c <= MAXVAL; c++)
            {
                unsigned long long int d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                if ( a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d )
                {
                    printf("a=%lld, b=%lld, c=%lld, d=%lld\n",a,b,c,d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: Does it matter if the output order changes?

Comment: @Eljay, not at all.

Comment: Partition the work amongst a pool of threads.  The [thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) constructor documentation at cppreference has an example of using `std::thread`.  Since your loop is mostly I/O bound with the `printf`, it's unlikely that parallelizing the work will have much impact (since I/O is a single resource, so has to handle concurrent access by marshaling operations into a single operation at a time).

Comment: @Eljay I guess that solutions to the brute-force algorithm are rare, so no, the code is not I/O bound (I tried to run the code, and there are 7 solutions with a<=25)

Comment: One obvious optimization (which has nothing to do with parallelisation) would be to move the calculation of `a*a` and `b*b` from the inner loop. The compiler might do that for you but why take the chance.

Comment: I think you're going to benefit more from an improved algorithm than from running a brute force search in parallel. http://math.colgate.edu/~integers/u73/u73.pdf

Comment: @JerryCoffin I also thought at first that the algorithm is searching for Pythagorean quadruples, but there is the added constrain that a+b+c+d=100'000 (which does not make sense to me).

Comment: @prapin: I don't think he's trying to find all of them, but Pythagorean quads are enough less common than numbers that add up to the right sum, that it seems likely that it'll be faster to generate quads, then check for the right sum than to generate the right sum, then check whether it's a Pythagorean quad.

Comment: @prapin • I missed that the `printf` was called rarely, rather than called every iteration.  Not I/O bound; my bad.

Comment: Before considering parallelism, try loop unrolling.  Branches and jumps are expensive.  Processors have to go through branch prediction and worst case, have to reload the instruction cache.  You want to increase the quantity of data processing instructions and less the branching.  Search the internet for "C++ loop unrolling".  Some compilers may perform loop unrolling at higher optimization levels.

Comment: ```d = MAXVAL - a - b - c```: the value for ```d``` can easily become negative according to the range allowed for ```a```, ```b``` and ```c```. And this is not a good idea since ```d``` is supposed to be unsigned. I guess that the end condition for the 3 loops should be adapted to take this into account (and the ranges should be smaller).

Answer (score 2):

To parallize the code extract a function and spawn different threads for the outest loop, with smaller limits, e.g. for 2 threads (you may also spawn the threads in a for loop and add them to a list):

```cpp
const unsigned long long int MAXVAL = 100000;
void Calc(long int aStart, long int aEnd){
    unsigned long long int a;
    for (a = aStart; a <= aEnd; a++)
    {
        unsigned long long int b;
        for (b = a + 1; b <= MAXVAL; b++)
        {
            unsigned long long int c;
            for (c = b + 1; c <= MAXVAL; c++)
                {
                    unsigned long long int d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                    if ( a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d )
                        {
                            printf("a=%lld, b=%lld, c=%lld, d=%lld\n",a,b,c,d);
                        }
                }

        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int step = MAXVAL/2;
    long int begin = 1;
    long int end = begin + step;
    std::thread t1(Calc, begin, end);
    begin = end;
    end = begin + step;
    std::thread t2(Calc, begin, end);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

But in case you want the fastest resutls, you may do some optimizations.

- `a*a` and `b*b` is calculated very often, calculate them once and reuse the result.
- `d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;` `a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d` can be formulated as a quadratic equation, which can be solvend analytical. So the whole inner loop can be replaceb by a check, if the result (`c`) is an integer or not.

Comment: Be careful not to spawn too many threads have a look at std::hardware_concurrency for a hint on a good maximum.  Also note the the printf output will probably be garbage (mixed output from various threads).

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag) added in C++17, like `std::execution::par`, which will use as many threads as your CPU has support for. Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

struct result {
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned long long b;
    unsigned long long c;
    unsigned long long d;
};

int main() {
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::vector<result> res;
    const unsigned long long MAXVAL = 100000;
    std::for_each(std::execution::par,
                  counting_iterator{1ull},
                  counting_iterator{MAXVAL + 1},
                  [&](auto a) {
                      for(unsigned long long b = a + 1; b <= MAXVAL; b++) {
                          const auto ab = a * a + b * b;
                          for(unsigned long long c = b + 1; c <= MAXVAL; c++) {
                              unsigned long long d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                              if(ab + c * c == d * d) {
                                  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                                  res.emplace_back(result{a, b, c, d});
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  });

    // print the result
    for(result& r : res) {
        std::cout << r.a << ' ' << r.b << ' ' << r.c << ' ' << r.d << '\n';
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `counting_iterator` in the standard library, so you'll have to implement it yourself, or use an existing implementation, like [`boost::counting_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html).

Comment: my vscode throws error: "No member named 'execution' in namespace 'std'clang(no_member)"

Comment: @Rebel You need at least C++17 to use the execution policies, so compile with `-std=c++17` (or `-std=c++20`). You may also need to link with `tbb`. At least I think clang uses `tbb`, so `-ltbb`.

Comment: I was able to get things on VS based on C++20. However, there is an issue with with the signature of foreach function that not sure how to resolve. I have attached the snapshot of VS.

Answer (score 1):

The algoritm is simple enough to try on gpu easily. Following code performs brute-force computation for MAXVAL=16k in 1 second and MAXVAL=32k in 4 seconds, using OpenCL and two GPUs:

- each `a` value is computed by a gpu-thread in OpenCL
- multiple GPUs are run with a work distribution ratio depending on their performance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "gpgpu.hpp"
int main()
{

    try
    {
        const int MAXVAL = 1024*32; 

        GPGPU::Computer computer(GPGPU::Computer::DEVICE_GPUS); 


        computer.compile(
            std::string("#define MAXVAL ") + std::to_string(MAXVAL) + std::string(
            R"(

            kernel void parallel(global int * output) 
            { 
                int threadId=get_global_id(0); 
                int result = 0;
                int a = threadId + 1;                
                for(int b = a+1;b<=MAXVAL;b++)
                    for(int c = b+1; c<=MAXVAL; c++)
                    {
                        int d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                        if(a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d)
                            result = 1;
                    }
                output[threadId]=result;
             })"), "parallel");
        


        auto output = computer.createArrayOutput<int>("output",MAXVAL);


        // repeatation for benchmarking
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            size_t nanoSeconds;
            {
                GPGPU::Bench bench(&nanoSeconds);
                computer.compute(output, "parallel", 0, MAXVAL, 256);
            }
            std::cout << nanoSeconds / 1000000000.0f << " seconds" << std::endl;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAXVAL; i++)
            {
                if (output.access<int>(i) > 0)                
                    count++;                    
            }
            std::cout << count<<" threads found a solution." << std::endl;
        }
        

    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; // any error is handled here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With a better brute force (better work scheduling like giving equal work per thread by computing symmetrically per thread for both ends of values) it should work 2x fast per extra loop depth (4x for 3 loops).

Following version works 3x faster and maps two loops to threads where MAXVAL=16k means 256Million gpu-threads (0.35 seconds):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "gpgpu.hpp"
int main()
{

    try
    {
        const int MAXVAL = 1024*16; 

        GPGPU::Computer computer(GPGPU::Computer::DEVICE_GPUS); 


        computer.compile(
            std::string("#define MAXVAL ") + std::to_string(MAXVAL) + std::string(
            R"(

            kernel void parallel(global int * output) 
            { 
                const int threadId=get_global_id(0); 
                int result = 0;
                const int a = (threadId % MAXVAL) + 1;
                const int b = (threadId / MAXVAL) + 1;
                if(b>a)
                    for(int c = b+1; c<=MAXVAL; c++)
                    {
                        const int d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                        if(a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d)
                            result = 1;
                    }                
                output[threadId]=result;
             })"), "parallel");
        


        auto output = computer.createArrayOutput<int>("output",MAXVAL*MAXVAL);


        // compute, uses all GPUs and other devices with load-balancing to give faster devices more job to minimize overall latency of kernel (including copy latency too)       
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            size_t nanoSeconds;
            {
                GPGPU::Bench bench(&nanoSeconds);
                computer.compute(output, "parallel", 0, MAXVAL*MAXVAL, 256);
            }
            std::cout << nanoSeconds / 1000000000.0f << " seconds" << std::endl;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAXVAL*MAXVAL; i++)
            {
                if (output.access<int>(i) > 0)                
                    count++;                    
            }
            std::cout << count<<" threads found a solution." << std::endl;
        }
        

    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl; // any error is handled here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Actual computation is even faster because this one has too big output array (1GB) which takes nearly 30 milliseconds to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Since `d = MAXVAL - a - b - c`, it can become negative because of the range definition for `a`, `b` and `c`. Since `d` is supposed to be unsigned, I guess this is not a good thing.

Here is a modification that should ensure that `d` is always positive (not sure however that it still matches the initial intent).

As a matter of fact, it should as well speed up the whole thing since the 3 for-loops should iterate less items (something like a 6x speedup).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef unsigned long long int Int;
    
    const Int MAXVAL = 100000;
    Int a;
    for (a = 1; a <= MAXVAL; a++)
    {
        Int b;
        for (b = a + 1; a+b <= MAXVAL; b++)
        {
            Int c;
            for (c = b + 1; a+b+c <= MAXVAL; c++)
            {
                Int d = MAXVAL - a - b - c;
                if ( a*a + b*b + c*c == d*d )
                {
                    printf("a=%5ld, b=%5ld, c=%5ld, d=%5ld\n",a,b,c,d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 
    return 0;
}
```